# Transfer files from Oracle RDS to S3 bucket located in a different AWS account

Tags: oracle, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I would like to transfer files from Oracle RDS to S3 bucket. This article from AWS- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/oracle-s3-integration.html describes how this can be achieved. But the solution works only when the RDS and the S3 bucket are in the same AWS region. Could anyone help how to copy files when the S3 is in a different AWS account.

Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

as of now i don't think there is a direct/documented method to copy directly from rds to s3 in another account . but you can copy the files to s3 bucket in the same account and do a cross account copy from s3 .
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/copy-s3-objects-account/